# Allow two header content type - Javascript react axios

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, rest, http-headers

I want to accept two content type in axios response content type as follows:
1)

```
     responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/pdf'
    }
```

2)

```
  responseType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
```

How to combine both the header response types?

**Curent error:** PDF downloads but with no content.

**spring boot back end:** : Here is the backend REST service which either sends JSON or a PDF file as bytearray

```
@PostMapping(value = "/generateBarcode")
public ResponseEntity<?> generateBarcode(@Valid @RequestBody BarCodeRequest barCodeRequest, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return errorService.validationService(result); //Sends Json
    }
    return batchService.generateBarCode(barCodeRequest); //Sends PDF 
}
```

Actual Java code to flush the PDF: 
    public ResponseEntity flushPDF(String batchName, byte[] baos) {

```
    if (null != baos) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; " + batchName + ".pdf");
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("filename", batchName + SBGConstants.BARCODE_FILES_EXT);
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");
        headers.add("TEST", "success");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(baos.length)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(baos);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Failed to generate barcode PDF", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Any thoughts on fixing the response header is much appreciated! I'm able to achieve either PDF output or JSON messages from the backend till now. Not combined together.

Thanks.

Comment: By parsing buffer as JSON using JSON.stringify() helps to convert arraybuffer result to json.